# How to use Google Realtime API with Java?

Tags: java, google-drive-realtime-api

Is there any way to use [Google Realtime API](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/realtime/overview) from an application written in Java? I was looking into using the features provided by this API to build an Android application, but so far I didn't succeed to find any related Java library.

Answer (score 1):

The core [Realtime API](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/realtime/faq#how_does_the_realtime_api_relate_to_the_google_drive_api) is available only in Javascript. The import/export APIs are standard REST APIs accessible from any platform.